# How to use third party javascript library with ionic4 and capacitor?

Tags: angular, ionic4, capacitor

What is the correct way to install third party javascript libraries with an Ionic 4 angular app and Capacitor?

---

I tried to install the [crunker library](https://github.com/jackedgson/crunker) as follows:

```
npm install crunker --save
```

Then ...

```
import * as crunker from 'crunker';
...
export class MyPage {

  constructor() {}

  doX() { 
     const crunk = new crunker.Crunker();
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Followed by:

```
npm run build
npx cap copy
npx cap copy ios
npx cap open ios
```

However, when I hit the page in the IOS simulator, I see the following error in the console:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new crunker__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__"Crunker"')

---

Update:

I have tried adding crunker to angular.json, as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55329218/1033422), but I get the same error.

Comment: Look at my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open [angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config) and add script into **scripts** section.

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/crunker/dist/crunker.js"
]
```

Important thing is to do `npx cap copy` after rebuild project

Comment: @chris have you runned npx cap copy after cli restart and rebuild?

Comment: Yes.  It seemed that the solution was to do as suggested in BOTH your answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55329349/1033422

Comment: @ChrisSnow, this seems to be excessive: `import` will add `crunker` to your JS bundle, **nothing else is needed to use a 3rd party library**. Adding it to scripts means that the library will be added to your app twice: as part of the JS bundle **and** it will be loaded via a `<script>` tag. Try using either only `scripts` [as described here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts#global-scripts) or only `import` wherever you need `Crunker`

Answer (score 4):

Seems that class Crunker [is the default export](https://github.com/jackedgson/crunker/blob/master/src/crunker.js), so try:

```js
import Crunker from 'crunker';
```

E.g.

```js
import Crunker from 'crunker';
...
export class MyPage {

  constructor() {}

  doX() { 
     const crunk = new Crunker();
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```