# How to use Watermarkjs library with ionic capacitor?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, watermark, capacitor

**Problem**

Hi, I recently migrated an ionic cordova project to ionic capacitor following [this guide](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor).

I got everything working except for the [Watermarkjs library](https://github.com/brianium/watermarkjs), which I use to watermark pictures taken with the camera of an Android device.

The library used to work fine before the migration, but now everytime I use the functions defined in that library I get this log in Logcat:

`Capacitor: Handling local request: http://localhost/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD`

It seems the function is not being called properly.

**Code**

```
async takePicture(fieldId){
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality:20,
      allowEditing:false,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt
    });
  
    let finalImage = await this.addTextWatermark(image.base64String);  //problem begins here
    
    console.log("Image with watermark, " finalImage); // this is never printed out in logcat
  }

// Function that adds a watermark 
// reference: http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/text.html
addTextWatermark(base64String){
    let result = await watermark([base64String])
        .dataUrl(watermark.text.lowerLeft( 'Watermark text', '48px Josefin Slab', '#ffffff', 0.9) )
        .then( image  => {
          return image;
        }).catch(error => {
          return "error";
        })
    return result;
}
```

**What I've tried...**

- Adding watermarkjs script in `angular.json` *scripts* section and running `npx cap copy`, as suggested in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278045/how-to-use-third-party-javascript-library-with-ionic4-and-capacitor)

`angular.json` (excerpt)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/watermarkjs/dist/watermark.js"  <----- Added script here
            ]
          } ...
```

- Using different input types for the `watermark()` function. (file, blob, etc.)

I think the problem is related to not importing the functions properly.

If the library is incompatible with *ionic capacitor*...

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I think its `base64` issue and library not supports base64. try with `FILE_URI`.

Comment: Also try loading it via the other props for `Photo` and see if that works. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/camera#photo

Comment: Yes, as @NajamUsSaqib suggested, it was an issue with the `base64`. Adding the line: `let base64String = await this.b64.encodeFile(image.path);` (image path is a `FILE_URI` )  Then passing that `base64String` to `addTextWatermark()` worked.  WatermarkJS was working properly, the problem was that since I was passing a strange dataURL it was trying to resolve it as a web URL of an image...